# Alter a formula in VBA and show it in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to write in VBA to write a formula into a cell that depends on other dynamic cells.

```
Dim cell1, cell2 as Range
set cell1 = Range("A1")
set cell2 = Range("A2")
```

'I can't hardcode A1 and A2 because the cells will change later by incrementing the rows

'I want to display in B1 `=(1+cell1)*(1+cell2)` using references, but when I see it on excel, it says `=(1+A1)*(1+A2)`

and for B2 it will be `=(1+A2)*(1+A3)`

How can I achieve this in VBA?

Comment: What is A1 + 1 ?   Are you adding a row or column ? Should it be B1 ? or A2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ... combination of INDIRECT to translate a string "A1" to a cell reference. and OFFSET to adjust rows/cols from a given reference.

```
  Sub test()
     Dim s1 As String
     Dim add_row As Integer
     Dim add_col As Integer

     s1 = "A1"

     add_row = 2
     add_col = 1

     Range("A1").Value = "=offset(indirect(" + Chr(34) + s1 + Chr(34) + ")," + Str(add_row) + "," + Str(add_col) + ",1,1)"

  End Sub
```

[edit]
just realized, don't even need the indirect function in there:

this works just as well:

```
Range("A1").Value = "=offset(" + s1 + "," + Str(add_row) + "," + Str(add_col) + ",1,1)"
```

;)
[/edit]